# How can you make the button listens again on clicks after a drag and drop done after long click?

Tags: android, button, drag-and-drop, listener

How do you do this?

I have a button. That button has a longclicklistener and a clicklistener. Inside the longclick listener, it has a drag and drop functionality.

I tried to do this.. However after long click and drag and drop is already successful.. Button, could no longer detect the short and long click because it is stock in the drag and drop. Do you have a better design on doing this kind of logic? Thanks. How could you make the button listens the clicks after drag and drop?

This is what i done. I want my program to run in the background so I did use Service.

In the Oncreate()

1. Initialise my view.
2. Initialise my button (findbyview).
3. Add a longclick and a normal click listener.

   3.1 on longclick, add touchlistener to the button and add
             ondraglistener to the views.

   3.1.1  After drag and drop, button should again able to listen the clicks. (how can you
             do this?

Appreciate your help guys. I am stuck.

This is my code.

```
public class MainPowerAndVolumeService extends Service {


private ViewGroup mView;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ImageButton mainButton;
private Button testButton;


@Override
public IBinder
onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


public void onCreate( ) {
    super.onCreate();


    /*This will make your window or layout to be overlay and of course you can click the buttons*/

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
    Log.d("tok", " Window Manager activated");


    /*This will load the main.xml view through inflate*/
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Log.d("tok", " Window Manager systemservice");

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    mView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);


    mainButton =(ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.MainButton);
    mainButton.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

    wm.addView(mView,params);
    Log.d("tok", "add mview");

    buttonListener();






}



public void buttonListener(){

    mainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(MainPowerAndVolumeService.this,
                    "ImageButton (selector) is clicked!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    mainButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            mView.findViewById(R.id.topRight).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
            mView.findViewById(R.id.topLeft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
            mView.findViewById(R.id.bottomRight).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
            mView.findViewById(R.id.bottomLeft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
            mainButton.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

            return false;
        }
    });

}




public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);

}
```

}

Comment: You could remove the listener after the drag-drop finish. Post code so you can get more precise answer.

Comment: Okay I will post my code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use of this

```
 checkIn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Long preess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have noticed that you are using return true instead of false. Does that boolean return value has any uses?

Comment: @toksis..yes,when u clicked on long clicked listener then your your simple button click listener will not called.

Comment: @toksis-just use and u will see the difference